# How to change Strike through color?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

```
NSMutableAttributedString *str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Old price"];
[str addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName
                        value:@2
                        range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])];
```

How to change striking color ?

Comment: Unique question ... :)

Comment: Using `NSStrikethroughColorAttributeName` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
NSDictionary *attrs = @{ NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f],
                         NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle),
                         NSStrikethroughColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor],
                         NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor yellowColor]
                       };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableAttributedString *str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Old price"];
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [str length]);
[str addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName value:@2 range:range];
[str addAttribute:NSStrikethroughColorAttributeName value:[UIColor greenColor] range:range];
[str addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor greenColor] range:range];
```